# The string "ďťż" appears on my page randomly but only in firefox. IE and chrome don't have this problem.

Tags: php, javascript, html

Nothing actually prints that anywhere in my code. So far i've found it in only two places one of them being:

```
<li class="spatiu"> </li>
<li class="memento_li"> 
    <div id="afisare_alerte">
    <script language="javascript">
        afisare_alerte_php();
    </script>
</div> 
</li>';
```

and this is "afisare_alerte_php()"

```
xmlhttp_alerte.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp_alerte.readyState == 4) {                                               
         if(document.getElementById("afisare_alerte").innerHTML=xmlhttp_alerte.responseText){
         }
         schimbare_tip_cursor('default');
    }
    else{
        schimbare_tip_cursor('progress');
    }
};
```

well the ajax part of it.

the file it loads is

```
<?php
    echo'
    0 Notificari
';
?>
```

and the output :

```
ďťż 0 Notificari
```

Comment: Sounds like a character set marker of some sort.

Comment: It could be a matter of charset where \n\t becomes the weird characters

Comment: i removed the newline from the echo, still getting it.

Comment: also, the charset i'm using is utf-8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sequence `ďťż` is called the [Windows Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). It shows up whenever you save a file as UTF in most Windows programs. So the problem here is that you must be serving that ajax endpoint from a Windows server, and the server is configured to output a BOM. How to fix this depends on what web server you are using.

Comment: If you're using Microsoft Expressions Web and get this problem use this to solve it [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295463.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Those characters actually do exist in your code, you just can't see them. Some editors add these when the file is saved as UTF. Too see the characters, open your code in an ISO-only editor (e.g. a simple notepad program). You'll be able to see the `ďťż` then, and you can do a global search/replace to just remove all instances of it. Then save your file.

Comment: i've tried this with every file that includes/is included in anything related to that piece of screen. haven't found anything. tried it with notepad. Can you suggest a text editor or a more detailed course of action to take to find these elusive characters?

Comment: Notepad I think also supports UTF8, so that's not simple enough. Try opening it in your regular text editor, then changing the character encoding `iso-8859-1`. How to do that will depend on your particular text editor.

Comment: aparently it was AJAX that for some reason added those characters at the begining of the responseText. But i still haven't found out why

Comment: @Bogdan, I added another answer explaining more about what these characters are and why an AJAX request might cause them to show up.

Comment: Thanks I was about to add an answer and a fix code but I don't have 100 reputation so I can't yet.

Comment: @Bogdan, well I just up-voted your question (it was a good question, after all), so that's 5 more points on your way to 100... ;)

Comment: Just a side note: I wasn't able to get the characters to show with any text editor that runs on windows. However i did manage to find them with a hex editor.